# How to find a difference between previous and current values in Excel Cell?

Tags: excel, range, worksheet-function, vba

A1 = time start using cntrl+shift+ which shows 4:00 AM

B1 = time end using cntrl+shift+ which shows 8:00 AM

C1 = time between using =MOD(B1-A1,1) which shows 4:00:00

D1 = time from cell C1 converted into minutes using =C1*1440 which shows 240 minutes

**E1 = D1 new value - D1 old value (Example: if old value was 240, and new is 360, then 360-240 = 120.)**

The bold is what I want, and I can only hope you guys can understand what I am trying to accomplish. I'll try to be clearer if need be as you wish. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is the new value? on the next row (D2)?

Comment: The new value will be on E1 which contains the old value of D1 subtracted from new value of D1.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm still not following. What do you mean by "the new value of D1"? How can D1 have more than one value?

Comment: If I update the end time to 9:00 AM in B1, C1 will formulate and output 5:00:00. D1 will then get the value of that and multiply by 1440 to convert to minutes, which will then be D1 = 300. I want E1 to subtract the old value of D1 (240), from new value of D1 (300), and output E1 = 60 minutes.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this will require a VBA solution. I suggest you research worksheet events, develop some code, and post back here with questions/problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to find a difference between new and old values entered, for example, in "D1" (on cell change event) and display it cell "E1", the general solution is shown in following code snippet (see Listing 1):

*Listing 1*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Column = 4 And Target.Row = 1 Then
        'new val
        newVal = Range("D1").Value
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        'old val
        oldVal = Range("D1").Value
        Range("D1").Value = newVal
        'diff between new and old val
        Range("E1").Value = newVal - oldVal
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Pertinent to your particular case (assuming that time is entered by pressing combination `CTRL+SHIFT+:` (or just typed) in either cell "A1" or "B1", the modified code snippet is shown in Listing 2.

*Listing 2*

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    If Target.Row = 1 And (Target.Column = 1 Or Target.Column = 2) Then
        'new val
        a1 = Range("A1").Value
        b1 = Range("B1").Value
        newVal = Range("D1").Value

        'disable events and undo
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Application.Undo
        'old val
        oldVal = Range("D1").Value

        'diff between new and old val
        diff = newVal - oldVal

        Range("A1").Value = a1
        Range("B1").Value = b1
        Range("E1").Value = diff

        're-enable events
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

On a separate note, your Worksheet computation could be simplified if you use a formula for a difference in minute like: `=MOD(B1-A1,1)*1440` entered in a single cell (e.g. "D1") instead of using the couple ("C1" and "D1"). Also, the entire computation could be performed solely in VBA module, updating "E1" value based on entries in "A1" and "B1" (no need for "C1" and "D1" in this scenario).

Hope this will help. Best regards,

Comment: Hello Alex! This works as far as inputting the subtracted value into E1. Unfortunately, E1 and D1 are only working if I input, manually, a number into D1, which ignores A1, B1, and C1. D1 is =C1*1440 and outputs blank. This works for the most part, but doesn't want to take the value of a formulated cell...

Comment: @Serendipitepic: Hello! As a stated in my solution, you can extend this code snippet with whatever logic is pertinent to your case. The concept is clearly demonstrated: Use Worksheet_Change event and Target, which could include any changes in cells A1, B1 and C1. Best of luck with your project. Kind regards,

Comment: Sorry, but I have no idea how to include the changes in Cells A1, B1, and C1 into this code...

Comment: Please see the extended answer pertinent to you case. Best regards,

Comment: Alex you are a genius! This worked great! One last thing, how would I be able to make this work for all cells under it? As in the whole columns?

Comment: @Serendipitepic, if you find an answer that solves your problem, please select it as an answer.  It serves several purposes, most of which is that when people search for questions, they can see if it was answered, and that is very useful to know when searching to either help unanswered questions to find out that they DID have an answer, only after reading for 5 minutes through comments.  Also, it is very nice to see your answer was appreciated, and it grants YOU and the Answerer reputation points.

Comment: @Serendipitepic: I am glad it works for you. May I ask you kindly to mark this answer accepted, and if you have any other questions, please post it separately? Best of luck with your project. Thanks and regards,

Comment: My question pertains to having the code work for a range of cells under it, but yes, I can make another post. Thank you once again for the help.

Comment: Many thanks! Good luck with your project. Kind regards,