# "Out of Stack Space" Error triggered by simple Worksheet_Calculate

Tags: excel, vba

Basically what I'm trying to do is record the value of a particular cell (in this case `B26`) when the worksheet opens, and then copy the value of `B26` to cell `B25` if the value of `B26` changes.

In `Module1` I have the following code:

```
Public PrevVal As Variant
```

In `ThisWorkbook` I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
PrevVal = Sheet13.Range("B26").Value
End Sub
```

And in `Sheet13` I have the following code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("B26").Value <> PrevVal Then
    Range("B25").Value = Range("B26").Value
    PrevVal = Range("B26").Value
End If

End Sub
```

The strange thing is that this code seemed to be working fine, then started giving me an "Out of Stack Space" error seemingly out of the blue (error occurs on the `If Range("B26").Value <> PrevVal Then` line of code.

If it helps, cell B26 is a formula that returns either "low", "moderate", or "high" based on the value of another cell. Here is the formula:

```
=IF('Source Data'!$C$53=0,"low",IF(AND('Source Data'!$C$53>0,'Source Data'!$C$53<3),"moderate",IF('Source Data'!$C$53>2,"high","N/A")))
```

Any idea why I'm suddenly getting this error?

Comment: In addition to the answer already provided, which I agree with, there was recently a question posted that you might find interest in reading, that might change how you are going about this, using a worksheet_Change event, and checking the TARGET cell. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27578950/how-to-find-a-difference-between-previous-and-current-values-in-excel-cell/27583677?noredirect=1#comment43615038_27583677

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is calling itself in a continuous loop when the the `PreVail` range updates, you can turn off the code loop by disabling `Events` like so (so the `Calculate` event runs only once, including any updates if *PrevVal* is different to B26)

See this [MSFT link](http://support.microsoft.com/KB/126090) for general information as to the *Out of Stack Space* error.

Good question!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Range("B26").Value <> PrevVal Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("B25").Value = Range("B26").Value
    PrevVal = Range("B26").Value
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Good call! That fixed the "Out of Stack Space" error.

However, now the next step of my code is no longer functioning, which basically looks for either "low", "moderate", or "high" in cell `B25` and determines whether certain images are visible or not using `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)`

Is this because the change to cell `B25` is no longer registered as an "event"?

Comment: @CDutton next step being? :)

Comment: Nevermind, got it to work! I just had to set the value of `B25` at another point in the code. Thanks for the help @brettdj!